# How to send mail to multiple recipients in Yii2 mailer

Tags: php, email, yii, phpmailer, mailer

This code is working for a single recipient but not for multiple recipients.How should I add multiple recipient into send() function in here.

```
//find price
$price = MDealPrice::model()->find("id=:id", array(':id' => $id));

// find deal
$deal = MDeal::model()->find("id=:id", array(':id' => $price->dealId));

//send email
app()->mailer->send($sendEmailAdd, 'orderAuthorizeEmail', array('deal' => $deal));
```

I tried like this also, But not worked.

```
//send email
app()->mailer->send(array('email1@domain.com','email2@domain.com'), 'orderAuthorizeEmail', array('deal' => $deal));
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you getting any error while running this code? if yes then please post it here.

Comment: I didn't get any error. @AlbertAkki

Comment: please get the last line in one variable and print_r that part and also make sure YII_DEBUG is true in index.php. also there will be one error_log file in the folder that will have the log of error if any so that you can track what is the issue.

Comment: did you tried to send it with single email id? if not then please try it. without passing array in send function just pass single email id in string.

Comment: Yes I tried it with single email id in string format. It works properly @AlbertAkki

Comment: then try with comma separated email id in string instead in array.

Comment: are you mean like this ? @AlbertAkki
`array('email1@domain.com , email2@domain.com')`

Comment: No. just pass string like this : " email1@domain.com, email2@domail.com".

Comment: It's worked for me. Thanks @AlbertAkki

Comment: wc. let me add this in answer so other user will get help if having same problem :)

Comment: it would be great if you upvote the answer :) @rokz92

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with below solution it will work

```
 app()->mailer->send('email1@domain.com,email2@domain.com', 'orderAuthorizeEmail', array('deal' => $deal));
```

just add your email ids comma separated string in send function instead to pass array of email ids.